# Override form submit event with jQuery ajax post

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I think I'm overriding the form submit correctly. However, instead of `//HIDE FORM` in the `done` event, I get the POST's json string (if the submit button is outside the form it works fine but I kinda need it in the form).

Form

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new{})
{
    //Form inputs
    <button type="submit" class="button-submit">Submit</button>
}
```

Script (in an init()):

```
$('.button-submit').bind('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (formIsValid) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'controller/action',
            type: 'POST',
            data: form.serialize()
        }).done(function(data) {
            if (data.success) {
                //HIDE FORM
            } else {
                //error
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

In Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Action(Model model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //Code...
    }
    return Json(model);
}
```

How do I keep the submit button in the form, use an ajax post, and return to hide the form and stay on the same page?

Comment: rather than binding `.bind('submit'...` I would do `.on('click'...`. Not totally sure if it helps though :)

Comment: What exactly are you asking? How to hide the form?

Comment: @Mackan Totally helps. One of the questions I looked up said to `.bind('submit'...`. I feel dumb now but thank you. Could you post the answer and maybe why this needs the `.on('click'...`?

Comment: @ajRichardson I use jQuery to hide the form. The ajax request was taking me to a new url with the json result. I want to stay on the same page. The `.on('click'...` fixed my issue.

Comment: @mackan Yes. `$(function() { Namespace.init(); });` The ajax request is inside the `init()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
$('.button-submit').bind('submit', function(e) {
```

To:

```
$('.button-submit').on('click', function(e) {
```

The reason your bind did not work is that you're binding a *button* to a *submit* event. If you want to use the *submit* event, this needs to be bound to the *form* to work.

> The submit event is sent to an element when the user is attempting to submit a form. It can only be attached to `<form>` elements

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
```

This would also work. But take note that using `on` instead of `bind` is *best practice* since jQuery 1.7.

Comment: As an extra note, I don't need `e.preventDefault();` so my code now reads `$('.button-submit').on('click', function() {` without the `e` as a parameter.

Comment: @christo8989 true. You either `return false` or  `e.preventDefault`. They do the same thing :)